# Mongod is crashing when querying the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS instance with nodejs and mongod running. The collection I am trying to query from has roughly 289248 documents in there.

Here is the code I am using to query my data:

```
var collection = db.collection('my_collection');
collection.find({ $and: [ 
        {"text" : {$regex : ".*"+keyword+".*"}}, 
        {"username" : username} 
    ] }).limit(10).toArray(function(err, docs) {
```

Now originally, I was having issues querying just a username `collection.find({"username":username})` because there are so many entries in mongo. So I started limiting my code and in the mongo console, I can set a limit of 30 and it results the results I am looking for.

However, then when I run this application on nodejs, when I query this command, it crashes my mongod service and I have to restart it. On the node server, limit of 1 works fine but limit of 5 does not. I can't simply use limit of 1 if there are many more results in the database. What can I do?

Comment: Have you checked the server logs, to see if there are any clues there?

Answer (score 0):

Does [not using $and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) make a difference? :

```
collection.find({text:{$regex:".*"+keyword+".*"},username: username})
```

I also wonder if the 'text' is a text index in which case it should be '$text'.

I also note that you use two variables in your query expression, and wonder if you have verified that those variables are defined.

Comment: The other issue is that just `collection.find({"username":username}).limit(10)` doesn't work for some queries either.

Comment: Are all the documents under 16MB? What is the version of MongoDB? Can you try the profiler to identify and compare the slow queries : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/